# Using Power Automate approval flow with multiple approvers based on assignment in SharePoint list

Tags: power-automate, sharepoint-list

Power Automate approval flow based on SharePoint list of Approvers

I am trying to make a Power Automate approval flow based on a list of approvers on a separate SharePoint list. This approval flow has 3 approvers, each subsequent. I am attempting to direct the flow to understand if it is Standard A type of approval (based on the user's selection when submitting to the portal), then it goes to Standard A approver's one after another. I have tried setting and initializing a variable, but I am unsure if my syntax is correct of if I'm grabbing the wrong column name.

Here are the current pictures of my Power Automate flow:

**First Step**

[image]

**Second Step**

[image]

**Third Step**

[image]

And this is what I have in my Approver Matrix List -- I really only need Approval Type and the list of approvers:

**Approver Matrix List**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Select action to only retrieve the emails of the approvers found in the matching item of the Approval Matrix list. After that you can join those email addresses from that array together as one semi colon separated string value.

Below is an example

*1. Expression for the From field within the Select action*

```
first(outputs('Get_items')?['body/value'])['Approvers']
```

*2. Use the Email in the Map field (make sure you switch it first to text mode with the button on the right side)*

*3. Expression for the Assigned To field in the approval action*

```
join(body('Select'), ';')
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, 

Thanks for your response but I'm getting an error at the first "Start and wait for an approval step" Error" - The request failed. Error code: 'InvalidApprovalCreateRequestAssignedToNoValidUsers'. Error Message: 'Required field 'assignedTo' contained no valid users in the organization'.

I used the join statement you provided in the Assigned to field. Any suggestions?

Comment: Are all accounts/emails used valid users in your org? Or are some external users for example? Are you able to manually select them in that same dropdown (that is a good way to double check if they are valid). https://nishantrana.me/2021/11/03/fixed-invalidapprovalcreaterequestassignedtonovalidusers-error-message-required-field-assignedto-contained-no-valid-users-in-the-organization/